# Spark Dataframe :How to add a index Column : Aka Distributed Data Index

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I read data from a csv file ,but don't have index.

I want to add a column from 1 to  row's number.

What should I do,Thanks   (scala)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

With Scala you can use:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 

df.withColumn("id",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
```

You can refer to this [exemple](https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2016/05/24/generate-unique-ids-for-each-rows-in-a-spark-dataframe/) and scala [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#monotonically_increasing_id()).

With Pyspark you can use:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id 

df_index = df.select("*").withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Comment: I'm wondering why the code you wrote for scala won't work for pyspark. i.e. `df.withColumn("id",monotonicallyIncreasingId)`

Comment: The scala code worked. Thanks 
However I am getting following warning "warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details"

Comment: monotonicallyIncreasingId does not guarantee that "id" will be "from 1 to row's number". From the doc: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#monotonically_increasing_id--  "The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not consecutive"

Comment: I noticed that too. You can have the id starting with 1 by using the following 
 df.withColumn("id",monotonicallyIncreasingId+1). It works fine upto a certain level, beyond which the id's are almost 15 digit.

Comment: Starting from Spark 2.0.0 the function `monotonicallyIncreasingId` has been deprecated. The corresponding function is, as in the case of the PySpark example, `monotonically_increasing_id()`.

Answer (score 47):

**monotonically_increasing_id** - The generated ID is guaranteed to be monotonically increasing and unique, but not consecutive.

*"I want to add a column from 1 to row's number."*

Let say we have the following DF

```
+--------+-------------+-------+
| userId | productCode | count |
+--------+-------------+-------+
|     25 |        6001 |     2 |
|     11 |        5001 |     8 |
|     23 |         123 |     5 |
+--------+-------------+-------+
```

To generate the IDs starting from 1

```
val w = Window.orderBy("count")
val result = df.withColumn("index", row_number().over(w))
```

This would add an index column ordered by increasing value of count.

```
+--------+-------------+-------+-------+
| userId | productCode | count | index |
+--------+-------------+-------+-------+
|     25 |        6001 |     2 |     1 |
|     23 |         123 |     5 |     2 |
|     11 |        5001 |     8 |     3 |
+--------+-------------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: The above works for small datasets; if you have a data > 100M it might be a problem to finish a job. Speaking from experience.

Comment: Is it possible to start `row_number()` from 0?

Answer (score 25):

How to get a **sequential id column** id[1, 2, 3, 4...n]:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import desc, row_number, monotonically_increasing_id
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df_with_seq_id = df.withColumn('index_column_name', row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())) - 1)
```

Note that row_number() starts at 1, therefore subtract by 1 if you want 0-indexed column

Answer (score 13):

> ***NOTE*** : Above approaches doesn't give a sequence number, but it does give increasing id.

Simple way to do that and ensure the order of indexes is like below.. `zipWithIndex`.

Sample data.

```
+-------------------+
|               Name|
+-------------------+
|     Ram Ghadiyaram|
|        Ravichandra|
|              ilker|
|               nick|
|             Naveed|
|      Gobinathan SP|
|Sreenivas Venigalla|
|     Jackela Kowski|
|   Arindam Sengupta|
|            Liangpi|
|             Omar14|
|        anshu kumar|
+-------------------+
```

---

```
    package com.example

import org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{LongType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row}

/**
  * DistributedDataIndex : Program to index an RDD  with
  */
object DistributedDataIndex extends App with Logging {

  val spark = builder
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName(this.getClass.getName)
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
    Seq("Ram Ghadiyaram", "Ravichandra", "ilker", "nick"
      , "Naveed", "Gobinathan SP", "Sreenivas Venigalla", "Jackela Kowski", "Arindam Sengupta", "Liangpi", "Omar14", "anshu kumar"
    )).toDF("Name")
  df.show
  logInfo("addColumnIndex here")
  // Add index now...
  val df1WithIndex = addColumnIndex(df)
    .withColumn("monotonically_increasing_id", monotonically_increasing_id)
  df1WithIndex.show(false)

  /**
    * Add Column Index to dataframe to each row
    */
  def addColumnIndex(df: DataFrame) = {
    spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame(
      df.rdd.zipWithIndex.map {
        case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq :+ index)
      },
      // Create schema for index column
      StructType(df.schema.fields :+ StructField("index", LongType, false)))
  }
}
```

Result :

```
+-------------------+-----+---------------------------+
|Name               |index|monotonically_increasing_id|
+-------------------+-----+---------------------------+
|Ram Ghadiyaram     |0    |0                          |
|Ravichandra        |1    |8589934592                 |
|ilker              |2    |8589934593                 |
|nick               |3    |17179869184                |
|Naveed             |4    |25769803776                |
|Gobinathan SP      |5    |25769803777                |
|Sreenivas Venigalla|6    |34359738368                |
|Jackela Kowski     |7    |42949672960                |
|Arindam Sengupta   |8    |42949672961                |
|Liangpi            |9    |51539607552                |
|Omar14             |10   |60129542144                |
|anshu kumar        |11   |60129542145                |
+-------------------+-----+---------------------------+
```

Comment: to show the difference between 2 approaches added `monotonically_increasing_id` as a column

Comment: What is the use of internal.logging package

Comment: @stack0114106  spark uses this I used same for my app

Answer (score 4):

As Ram said, `zippedwithindex` is better than monotonically increasing id, id you need consecutive row numbers. Try this (PySpark environment):

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, LongType

new_schema = StructType(**original_dataframe**.schema.fields[:] + [StructField("index", LongType(), False)])
zipped_rdd = **original_dataframe**.rdd.zipWithIndex()
indexed = (zipped_rdd.map(lambda ri: row_with_index(*list(ri[0]) + [ri[1]])).toDF(new_schema))
```

where original_dataframe is the dataframe you have to add index on and row_with_index is the new schema with the column index which you can write as

```
row_with_index = Row(
"calendar_date"
,"year_week_number"
,"year_period_number"
,"realization"
,"index"
)
```

Here, `calendar_date`, `year_week_number`, `year_period_number` and realization were the columns of my original dataframe. You can replace the names with the names of your columns. `index` is the new column name you had to add for the row numbers.

Comment: no need to write the new schema (except you want for code explicibility) => `indexed = (zipped_rdd.map(lambda ri: Row(*list(ri[0]) + [ri[1]])).toDF(new_schema))
`

Answer (score 0):

If you require a unique sequence number for each row, I have a slightly different approach, where a static column is added and is used to compute the row number using that column.

```
val srcData = spark.read.option("header","true").csv("/FileStore/sample.csv")
srcData.show(5)

+--------+--------------------+
|     Job|                Name|
+--------+--------------------+
|Morpheus|       HR Specialist|
|   Kayla|              Lawyer|
|  Trisha|          Bus Driver|
|  Robert|Elementary School...|
|    Ober|               Judge|
+--------+--------------------+

val srcDataModf = srcData.withColumn("sl_no",lit("1"))
val windowSpecRowNum =  Window.partitionBy("sl_no").orderBy("sl_no")

srcDataModf.withColumn("row_num",row_number.over(windowSpecRowNum)).drop("sl_no").select("row_num","Name","Job")show(5)

+-------+--------------------+--------+
|row_num|                Name|     Job|
+-------+--------------------+--------+
|      1|       HR Specialist|Morpheus|
|      2|              Lawyer|   Kayla|
|      3|          Bus Driver|  Trisha|
|      4|Elementary School...|  Robert|
|      5|               Judge|    Ober|
+-------+--------------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this `monotonically_increasing_id()` it will become nightmare for you, data skewness will happens. Happened for me.

Answer (score 0):

The monotonically_increasing_id() function generates monotonically increasing 64-bit integers. The generated id numbers are guaranteed to be increasing and unique, but they are not guaranteed to be consecutive.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df_with_increasing_id = df.withColumn("monotonically_increasing_id", monotonically_increasing_id())
df_with_increasing_id.show()
```

we get the following results:

```
+-----+---+---------------------------+
| Name|Age|monotonically_increasing_id|
+-----+---+---------------------------+
|Alice| 10|                 8589934592|
|Susan| 12|                25769803776|
+-----+---+---------------------------+
```

The row_number() function generates numbers that are consecutive.

Combine this with monotonically_increasing_id() to generate two columns of numbers that can be used to identify data entries.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.window import *

window = Window.orderBy(col('monotonically_increasing_id'))
df_with_consecutive_increasing_id = df_with_increasing_id.withColumn('increasing_id', row_number().over(window))
df_with_consecutive_increasing_id.show()
```

we get the following results:

```
+-----+---+---------------------------+-------------+
| Name|Age|monotonically_increasing_id|increasing_id|
+-----+---+---------------------------+-------------+
|Alice| 10|                 8589934592|            1|
|Susan| 12|                25769803776|            2|
+-----+---+---------------------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

For SparkR:

(Assuming sdf is some sort of spark data frame)

`sdf<- withColumn(sdf, "row_id", SparkR:::monotonically_increasing_id())`