# How to create an unique autogenerated Id column in a spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

I have a dataframe where I have to generate a unique Id in one of the columns. This id has to be generated with an offset.
Because , I need to persist this dataframe with the autogenerated id , now if new data comes in the autogenerated id should not collide with the existing ones.
I checked the monotonically increasing function but it does not accept any offset . 
This is what I tried :

```
df=df.coalesce(1);
df = df.withColumn(inputCol,functions.monotonically_increasing_id());
```

But is there a way to make the monotonically_increasing_id() start from a starting offset ?

Comment: why do you need `coalesce(1)`? That puts all the data into one partition which can cause an OOM error and prevents spark from parallelizing anything.

Comment: related to scala [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52546904/647053)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply add to it to provide a minimum value for the id. Note that it is not guaranteed the values will start from the minimum value

```
.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id + 123)
```

Explanation: Operator `+` is overloaded for columns https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala#L642

Comment: if I coalesce the dataframe to 1 partition , will it guarantee that it starts from the minimum value and follows a sequence?

Comment: @AyanBiswas In Java `.withColumn("id", functions.monotonically_increasing_id().plus(123))` . At least with the current implementation it seems to start from min if there is just a single partition. If that is the case, you can also use something like `df.mapPartitions(_.zipWithIndex)...` (sorry scala) if you want to control the behaviour yourself

Comment: Thanks , I can ensure that it runs with a single partition , so It should work with monotonically_increasing_id as well , right ?

Comment: Yes, at least in its current implementation. According to https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#monotonically_increasing_id-- the partition number is used for high bits and the record number inside partitions for low bits. In case of just one partition, the high bits will be 0 and you get 0,1,2,...

Answer (score 6):

Or if you don't want to restrict your program into one only partition with `df.coalesce(1)` you can use `zipWithIndex` which starts with index = 0 as next:

```
lines = [["a1", "a2", "a3"],
            ["b1", "b2", "b3"],
            ["c1", "c2", "c3"]]

    cols = ["c1", "c2", "c3"]

    df = spark.createDataFrame(lines, cols)

    start_indx = 10
    df = df.rdd.zipWithIndex() \
           .map(lambda (r, indx): (indx + start_indx, r[0], r[1], r[2])) \
           .toDF(["id", "c1", "c2", "c3"])

    df.show(10, False)
```

In this case I set the `start_index = 10`. And this will be the output:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|id |c1 |c2 |c3 |
+---+---+---+---+
|10 |a1 |a2 |a3 |
|11 |b1 |b2 |b3 |
|12 |c1 |c2 |c3 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a rownumber to your columns and then add that to the maximum existing identity column, or your offset. Once it is set drop the rownumber attribute.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# Could also grab the exist max ID value
seed_value = 123

df = df.withColumn("row_number", sf.rowNumber().over(Window.partitionBy(sf.col("natural_key")).orderBy(sf.col("anything"))))

df = df.withColumn("id", sf.col("row_number")+seed_value)
```

Remember to drop the row_number attribute.

Comment: You want the partition over a constant, not the natural key!