# Spark SQL column doesn't exist

Tags: sql, pyspark

I am using Spark in databricks for this SQL command.
In the input_data table, I have a string for the st column. Here I want to do some calculations of the string length.
However, after I assign the length_s alias to the first column, I can not call it in the following columns. SQL engine gives out **Column 'length_s1' does not exist** error message. How can I fix this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW content_data (SELECT LENGTH(st) AS length_s, LENGTH(st)-LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(seq,'[AB]','')) AS AB_c,
length_s - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(seq, '[CD]', '') AS CD_c, CD_c+AB_c AS sum_c
FROM input_data)
```

Comment: you can't use aliases in the same select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use aliases in the same select

So do

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW content_data (
    SELECT 
        LENGTH(st) AS length_s
        , LENGTH(st)-LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(seq,'[AB]','')) AS AB_c,
        LENGTH(st) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(seq, '[CD]', '') AS CD_c
        , LENGTH(st) - LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(seq, '[CD]', '') + LENGTH(st)-LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(seq,'[AB]','')) AS sum_c
    FROM input_data
)
```

Comment: Thank you. It is very helpful. Can I ask another question? How can I generate an ID number in Spark SQL? In the python interface, Spark has the monotonically_increasing_id() function. But I do not know how to realize this function in SQL grammar.

Comment: best woulb be to ask a new question, but taake a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55341313/how-to-create-an-unique-autogenerated-id-column-in-a-spark-dataframe