# Error when trying zipWithIndex in java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

I tried adding a column which has row number using `zipWithIndex` as below in spark

```
val  df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1.0, 2.0), (0.0, -1.0), (3.0, 4.0), (6.0, -2.3))).toDF("x", "y")
val rddzip = df.rdd.zipWithIndex;
val newSchema = StructType(df.schema.fields ++ Array(StructField("rowid", LongType, false)))
val dfZippedWithId =  spark.createDataFrame(rddzip.map{ case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array(index))}, newSchema)
```

But Same thing I am trying to do in JAVA as below

```
JavaRDD<Row> rdd = (JavaRDD) df.toJavaRDD().zipWithIndex().map(t -> {
    Row r = t._1;
    Long index = t._2 + 1;
    ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Object item: JavaConverters.seqAsJavaListConverter(r.toSeq()).asJava()) {
        list.add(item);
    }
    return RowFactory.create(JavaConverters.seqAsJavaListConverter(t._1.toSeq()).asJava().add(t._2));
});
StructType newSchema = df.schema()
        .add(new StructField(name, DataTypes.LongType, true, Metadata.empty()));
return df.sparkSession().createDataFrame(rdd, newSchema);
```

I get this below error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 23.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 23.0 (T
ID 523, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
        at com.nielsen.media.mediaView.adintel.pivot.datareader.AIReportViewerProcessor.lambda$zipWithIndex$7245ab51$1(AIReportViewerProcessor.java:3071)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1040)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
```

Any help?

Comment: I think in this answer you find what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56171598/6770614

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in scala version you are passing to `spark.createDataFrame` `RDD[Row]` and in java you are passing `JavaPairRDD`, you should map it to `JavaRDD[Row]`.

```
        Dataset<Row> df = ss.range(10).toDF();
        df.show();

        JavaPairRDD<Row, Long> rddzip = df.toJavaRDD().zipWithIndex();
        JavaRDD<Row> rdd = rddzip.map(s->{
            Row r = s._1;
            Object[] arr = new Object[r.size()+1];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
                arr[i] = r.get(i);
            }
            arr[arr.length-1] = s._2;
            return RowFactory.create(arr);
        });

        StructType newSchema = df.schema().add(new StructField("rowid",
                DataTypes.LongType, false, Metadata.empty()));

        Dataset<Row> df2 = ss.createDataFrame(rdd,newSchema);

        df2.show();
```

```
    +---+
    | id|
    +---+
    |  0|
    |  1|
    |  2|
    |  3|
    |  4|
    |  5|
    |  6|
    |  7|
    |  8|
    |  9|
    +---+

    +---+-----+
    | id|rowid|
    +---+-----+
    |  0|    0|
    |  1|    1|
    |  2|    2|
    |  3|    3|
    |  4|    4|
    |  5|    5|
    |  6|    6|
    |  7|    7|
    |  8|    8|
    |  9|    9|
    +---+-----+
```

Comment: Yeah the Mapping I am not able to code the corresponding in java