# How to use an existing column as index in Spark's Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am 'translating' a python code to pyspark. I would like to use an existing column as index for a dataframe. I did this in python using pandas. The small piece of code below explains what I did. Thanks for helping.

```py
df.set_index('colx',drop=False,inplace=True)
# Ordena index
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

I expect the result to be a dataframe with 'colx' as index.

Comment: Spark DataFrames do not have a concept of an index (or order in general). You *can* do `df = df.sort("colx")` but that's primarily for display purposes and you can't rely on that order for computations (without using a `Window`). Or maybe you want to add a [`row_number` ordering by `colx`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46740396/5858851)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark Dataframe :How to add a index Column : Aka Distributed Data Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406887/spark-dataframe-how-to-add-a-index-column-aka-distributed-data-index)

Answer (score 1):

add index to pyspark dataframe as a column and use it

```
rdd_df = df.rdd.zipWithIndex()
df_index = rdd_df.toDF()
#and extract the columns
df_index = df_index.withColumn('colA', df_index['_1'].getItem("'colA"))
df_index = df_index.withColumn('colB', df_index['_1'].getItem("'colB"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it works with Spark. No such concept exists.

One can add [a column to an RDD zipWithIndex by convert DF to RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52546904/647053) and back, but that is a new column, so not the same thing.