# Convert dictionary of columns to Dataframe in from different dataframes : pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to combine columns from different dataframes into one for analysis. I am collecting all the columns I need into a dictionary.

I now have a dictionary like this -

```
newDFDict = {
    'schoolName': school.INSTNM,
    'type': school.CONTROL,
    'avgCostAcademicYear': costs.COSTT4_A, 
    'avgCostProgramYear': costs.COSTT4_P, 
    'averageNetPricePublic': costs.NPT4_PUB, 
}

{
 'schoolName': Column<b'INSTNM'>,
 'type': Column<b'CONTROL'>,
 'avgCostAcademicYear': Column<b'COSTT4_A'>,
 'avgCostProgramYear': Column<b'COSTT4_P'>,
 'averageNetPricePublic': Column<b'NPT4_PUB'>
}
```

I want to convert this dictionary to a Pyspark dataframe.

I have tried this method but the output is not what I was expecting -

```
newDFDict = {
    'schoolName': school.select("INSTNM").collect(),
    'type': school.select("CONTROL").collect(),
    'avgCostAcademicYear': costs.select("COSTT4_A").collect(), 
    'avgCostProgramYear': costs.select("COSTT4_P").collect(), 
    'averageNetPricePublic': costs.select("NPT4_PUB").collect(), 
}

newDF = sc.parallelize([newDFDict]).toDF()
newDF.show()
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|averageNetPricePublic| avgCostAcademicYear|  avgCostProgramYear|          schoolName|                type|
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| [[NULL], [NULL], ...|[[NULL], [NULL], ...|[[NULL], [NULL], ...|[[Community Colle...|[[1], [1], [1], [...|
+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Is it even possible? 
If possible, how?

Is this the right way to do this? If not, how can I achieve this?

Using pandas is not an option as data is pretty big (2-3 GB) and pandas is just too slow. I am running pyspark on my local machine.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: you might have joined 2 dataframes using common key and then .... you can select columns that are needed for your so called dictionary right? there is no common column for both dataframes ? collect is killer with OOM if data is more.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram there are 10 tables with a combined total of over 1900 columns. I was thinking instead of joining 10 tables and selecting maybe 40-50 columns, we can do it via dictionary..

Comment: what is wrong in  ***join*** or  ***union with all common columns*** as a single view/dataframe ? big no to collect... you are pulling all the data in to driver hence OOM

Comment: I am not understanding what you are trying to say. Also I should mention the only common key is row number.

Comment: see my example, if you dont have  join key you could go for union as below answer which is sql representation of your common dict fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are 2 options I'd suggest

#### Option1 (union case to build dictionary) :

You said, you have >=10 tables (which you want to build dictionary from ) which has common columns (such as for example 'schoolName','type' 'avgCostAcademicYear' ,'avgCostProgramYear' , 'averageNetPricePublic' are common columns ) then you can go for **union** or **unionByName** to form single consolidated. view of the data.

For example :

```
select 'schoolName','type' 'avgCostAcademicYear' ,'avgCostProgramYear' , 'averageNetPricePublic' from df1

 union  

select 'schoolName','type' 'avgCostAcademicYear' ,'avgCostProgramYear' , 'averageNetPricePublic' from df2
 ....
union
select 'schoolName','type' 'avgCostAcademicYear' ,'avgCostProgramYear' , 'averageNetPricePublic' from dfN
```

will give you consolidated view of your dictionary

#### Option 2: (in case you have common join columns only)

If you have some common join columns you can also go for standard joins no matter how many tables are present ..

for psuedo sql example :

```
select dictionary columns from table1,table2,table3,... tablen where join common columns in all tables (table1... tablen)
```

note miss any join column will lead to cartesian product

Comment: The only common column is row number. There are no common columns

Comment: may not be join you mean union wont work ? have you tried ?

Comment: Instead of creating dictionary after selecting columns from every table I am now joining after creating a new dataframe with the reqd columns using monotically_increasing_id(). So option 2

Comment: your monotonically increasing id is not incremental as sql row number be careful see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52546904/647053)

Comment: I plan to drop it anyway. It will not cause issues in join though right? (I am asking about mismatched joins)

Comment: check it you will understand I cant visualize from here

Comment: Can you modify your answer to join after selecting each column. I want to mark it as correct xD