# Can not deserialize PairRDD with different number of items in batches

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to `pyspark` and haven't worked with `spark` in general for a few years. Can someone explain what happens here:

```
import random
import pyspark

sc.stop()
sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local[*]')


xx = sc.parallelize(range(100))
yy = sc.parallelize(list(map(lambda x : x *2, range(100))))
print(xx.count())
print(yy.count())
zipped = xx.zip(yy)
print(zipped.collect())
```

Output:

```
ValueError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-a532cb7061c7> in <module>
     11 print(yy.count())
     12 zipped = xx.zip(yy)
---> 13 print(zipped.collect())
...  
...
ValueError: Can not deserialize PairRDD with different number of items in batches: (9, 8)
```

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is correct.

Comment: did u disprove me?

Comment: No, sorry, @thebluephantom, I work on that course on weekends. I will check it closer to the end of the week and hopefully confirm that all is correct.

Comment: look at the example in the link. success

Comment: If I just change xx and yy definition like: xx = sc.parallelize(range(100)).repartition(5)
yy = sc.parallelize(list(map(lambda x : x *2, range(100)))).repartition(5), it doesn't help, I still get: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 6.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 35, 192.168.0.171, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Can only zip RDDs with same number of elements in each partition

Comment: Read the link on the answer elsewhere - things work the way designed to, not how we think. they may / should

Comment: Do I need to use zipWithIndex?

Comment: From my findings & from others yes as it gives the same distribution over the partitions this giving equal numbers of entries. A premise for this type of approach.

Answer (score 0):

This means you must have the same partitioner with same number of partitions and same number of key values per partition, else the zipping will *not* work. 9 <> 8, for example.

For more info:
[Unable to write PySpark Dataframe created from two zipped dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63727512/unable-to-write-pyspark-dataframe-created-from-two-zipped-dataframes/63730296#63730296)

`rdd.glom().collect()`  shows that not all your xx and yy rdd's comply with same no. of elements per partition. That's the issue.

Comment: this answer is as much help as the error message itself. Can you provide a code snippet?